# problem with vim's enew command

Tags: vim

In Vim, the :enew command has a really irritating behavior - after I create a new file, type something and save it, an empty buffer/file is still present. Why is that and is there any way to prevent it? I'm tired of having to close all these empty buffers all the time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't make any sense, `:enew` only creates **one** new empty buffer and you say you are already writing text and saving it. It sounds like you are starting up vim without specifying a file, and using `:enew` as your first command, in which case you would then have **two** empty buffers. Why not use the new buffer that vim creates on startup?

Btw, `:set confirm` makes it easier to discard unused buffers.

Comment: You're right, it wasn't an enew problem. I should have investigated more before asking. The problem was that I had a "save" shortcut mapped to `:browse confirm saveas`. Changing that to `:browse confirm w` solves the issue. Thanks for your help.